# windows phone 8 - xaml not found error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have two pages in my application . both pages are in View Folder (`SplashScreen.xaml` and `GetPhoneNumber.xaml`). i specify `<DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="View/SplashScreen.xaml"/>`

after running this code i got an error => xaml not found. i create 2 xaml file in Root of application and repeat this scenario and problem doesn't exist

### SplashScreen.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SplashScreen : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _splashTimer;

    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _splashTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
    }

    void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_splashTimer != null)
        {
            _splashTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            _splashTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_splashTimer_Tick);
            _splashTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    void _splashTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _splashTimer.Stop();
        _splashTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(_splashTimer_Tick);
        _splashTimer = null;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GetPhoneNumber.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }

}
```

### SplashScreen.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Ghavamin.View.SplashScreen"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush}">
        <Image Height="169" Margin="41,255,57,344" Width="382" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Image/splash.jpg"/>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/your_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the exact path inside the xaml. It is specified as `Ghavamin.View.SplashScreen` which means your `SplashSceen.xaml` exists inside the `View` Folder. So, Change the xaml like below or include the exact path when calling Navigate() method.

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Ghavamin.SplashScreen"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush}">
        <Image Height="169" Margin="41,255,57,344" Width="382" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Image/splash.jpg"/>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created same folder and file structure like you. There is a problem with your file name. I have just rename "Splashscreen.xaml" to "Abc.xaml" and also rename all related classes. Then it is working fine for me. It may happen that "Splashscreen" word is somehow reserved by Windows phone OS. For now this is the solution for your issue.